# Why select after a join raises an exception in java spark dataframe?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data dataframes: left and right. They are the same consisting of three columns: `src relation, dest` and  have the same values.

1- I tried to joind these dataframes where the condition is the dst in left = the src in right. But it was not working. Where is error?

```
Dataset<Row> r = left
  .join(right, left.col("dst").equalTo(right.col("src")));
```

Result:

```
+---+---------+---+---+---------+---+
|src|predicate|dst|src|predicate|dst|
+---+---------+---+---+---------+---+
+---+---------+---+---+---------+---+
```

2- If I renamed `dst` in the left as dst, and the src column in the right as dst2, then I apply a join, it works. But if I try to select some column from the optained dataframe. It raises an exception. Where is my error?

```
 Dataset<Row> left = input_df.withColumnRenamed("dst", "dst2");
 Dataset<Row> right = input_df.withColumnRenamed("src", "dst2");  
 Dataset<Row> r = left.join(right, left.col("dst2").equalTo(right.col("dst2")));
```

Then:

```
left.show();
```

gives:

```
+---+---------+----+
|src|predicate|dst2|
+---+---------+----+
|  a|       r1| :b1|
|  a|       r2|   k|
|:b1|       r3| :b4|
|:b1|      r10|   d|
|:b4|       r4|   f|
|:b4|       r5| :b5|
|:b5|       r9|   t|
|:b5|      r10|   e|
+---+---------+----+
```

and

```
right.show();
```

gives:

```
+----+---------+---+
|dst2|predicate|dst|
+----+---------+---+
|   a|       r1|:b1|
|   a|       r2|  k|
| :b1|       r3|:b4|
| :b1|      r10|  d|
| :b4|       r4|  f|
| :b4|       r5|:b5|
| :b5|       r9|  t|
| :b5|      r10|  e|
+----+---------+---+
```

result:

```
+---+---------+----+----+---------+---+
|src|predicate|dst2|dst2|predicate|dst|
+---+---------+----+----+---------+---+
|  a|       r1| b1| b1  |      r10|  d|
|  a|       r1| b1| b1  |       r3| b4|
|b1 |       r3| b4| b4  |       r5| b5|
|b1 |       r3| b4| b4  |       r4|  f|
+---+---------+----+----+---------+---+


Dataset<Row> r = left
  .join(right, left.col("dst2").equalTo(right.col("dst2")))
  .select(left.col("src"),right.col("dst"));
```

result:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) dst#45 missing from dst2#177,src#43,predicate#197,predicate#44,dst2#182,dst#198 in operator !Project [src#43, dst#45];
```

3- suppose the selected works, how can add the obtained dataframe to the left dataframe.

Im working in Java.

Comment: Can you add the error which you are getting and code snippet as well.

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde check please the updated post

Comment: Can you try select(col("src"),col("dst")) or just  select("src", "dst"); After joining, it should create a different dataframe and might not recognize left and right.

Comment: Adding a show() and printSchema() or your data frames before and after the transformation really helps understanding your use case.

Comment: @ApurbaPandey in java we cant just use col(ColName).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using:

```
r = r.select(left.col("src"), right.col("dst"));
```

It seems that Spark does not find the lineage back to the `right` dataframe. Not shocking as it goes through a lot of optimization.

Assuming your desired output is:

```
+---+---+
|src|dst|
+---+---+
| b1|:b5|
| b1|  f|
|:b4|  e|
|:b4|  t|
+---+---+
```

You could use one of this 3 options:

## Using the `col()` method

```
Dataset<Row> resultOption1Df = r.select(left.col("src"), r.col("dst"));
resultOption1Df.show();
```

## Using the `col()` static function

```
Dataset<Row> resultOption2Df = r.select(col("src"), col("dst"));
resultOption2Df.show();
```

## Using the column names

```
Dataset<Row> resultOption3Df = r.select("src", "dst");
resultOption3Df.show();
```

Here is the complete source code:

```
package net.jgp.books.spark.ch12.lab990_others;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

/**
 * Self join.
 * 
 * @author jgp
 */
public class SelfJoinAndSelectApp {

  /**
   * main() is your entry point to the application.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SelfJoinAndSelectApp app = new SelfJoinAndSelectApp();
    app.start();
  }

  /**
   * The processing code.
   */
  private void start() {
    // Creates a session on a local master
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("Self join")
        .master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> inputDf = createDataframe(spark);
    inputDf.show(false);

    Dataset<Row> left = inputDf.withColumnRenamed("dst", "dst2");
    left.show();

    Dataset<Row> right = inputDf.withColumnRenamed("src", "dst2");
    right.show();

    Dataset<Row> r = left.join(
        right,
        left.col("dst2").equalTo(right.col("dst2")));
    r.show();

    Dataset<Row> resultOption1Df = r.select(left.col("src"), r.col("dst"));
    resultOption1Df.show();

    Dataset<Row> resultOption2Df = r.select(col("src"), col("dst"));
    resultOption2Df.show();

    Dataset<Row> resultOption3Df = r.select("src", "dst");
    resultOption3Df.show();
  }

  private static Dataset<Row> createDataframe(SparkSession spark) {
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "src",
            DataTypes.StringType,
            false),
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "predicate",
            DataTypes.StringType,
            false),
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "dst",
            DataTypes.StringType,
            false) });

    List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    rows.add(RowFactory.create("a", "r1", ":b1"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create("a", "r2", "k"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create("b1", "r3", ":b4"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create("b1", "r10", "d"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(":b4", "r4", "f"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(":b4", "r5", ":b5"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(":b5", "r9", "t"));
    rows.add(RowFactory.create(":b5", "r10", "e"));

    return spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
  }
}
```

Comment: When joining left and right, I have the following column: `src|predicate|dst2|dst2|predicate|dst`, And the printSchema of right dataframe is `root
 |-- dst2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- predicate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dst: string (nullable = true)` SO why dst is not recognized?

Comment: I think you should add a full show() and printSchema() to your question... It's not really readable here. It's fine to edit it. Could you also add the code you use to build `left` and `right` before the join?

Comment: Have a look if that helps. Happy to help more if needed.

Comment: thank you, Amazing. My last quetsion please is: what is the difference if do a sql query on the dataframe like:`input.registerTempTable("r7");
        
  Dataset<Row> r7 = spark.sql("SELECT  a.src, a.predicate, b.dst" + 
           "   FROM r7 a, r7 b" + 
           "   WHERE a.dst = b.src");` In this case which solution as an expert you prefer  and why?

Comment: @Moudi, just ask another question, tag me here and I’ll reply tough to reply in such a small space :). Glad I could help (you can upvote my solution then :) ).